# how to create a matrix in matlab of the desired format

Tags: matlab, matrix

i want to create a matrix of the desired format in matlab.The format of matrix is as below.

1     -i     1     -i    1    -i

-1    i      -1     i    -1    i

1     -i     1      -i    1    -i

-1    i     -1     i     -1     i

the size of matrix is 256x256

i have created a program but its giving me error.can anyone help me.

> eff=[256 256];
>
> for p=0:255
>       for q=0:255
>           if mod(p,2)=='0'
>               if mod(q,2)=='0'
>                   eff(p,q)=1;
>               else
>                   eff(p,q)=(0-i);
>               end
>
> ```
>     else
>         if mod(p,2)=='0'
>
>         eff(p,q)=-1;
>         else
>             eff(p,q)=0+i
>         end
>     end
> end end
> ```
>
> figure(3) imagesc(eff); colormap gray; axis off; axis square; PW0=[256
>   256]; PW1=[256 256]; PW2=[256 256]; PW3=[256 256];
>
> ```
>     for p=0:255
> for q=0:255
>     if eff(p,q)=='1'
>             PW0(p,q)=1
>             PW1(p,q)=0
>             PW2(p,q)=0
>             PW0(p,q)=0
>     else if eff(p,q)=='-i'
>             PW0(p,q)=0
>             PW1(p,q)=-i
>             PW2(p,q)=0
>             PW0(p,q)=0
>
>
>     else
>         if eff(p,q)=='1'
>             PW0(p,q)=0
>             PW1(p,q)=0
>             PW2(p,q)=-1
>             PW0(p,q)=0
>
>         else
>             PW0(p,q)=0
>             PW1(p,q)=0
>             PW2(p,q)=0
>             PW0(p,q)=-i
>         end
>
>         end
>     end
> end
>     end
> ```

the error is as below 
??? Attempted to access eff(0,0); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Error in ==> Untitled at 18
                eff(p,q)=0+i

??? Attempted to access eff(0,0); index must be a positive integer or logical.

Error in ==> Untitled at 18
                eff(p,q)=0+i

can anybody help?

Comment: Take a look at `repmat`, and please use propper code indention, it's impossible to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `repmat` instruction in order to repeat the matrix multiple times (http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

```
a = [1 -i; -1 i];
b = repmat(a,128,128);
```

For the next time remember that Matlab is not indexing from 0, it starts at 1. That's why you are getting an error of "index must be positive"

Comment: when giving this its gving infinte loop

Comment: repmat is givng infinte loop

Comment: @SidharthaRamachandran What do you mean by "*giving infinite loop*"?

Comment: @SidharthaRamachandran this cannot give an infinite loop because is not a loop. I tried myself these two lines and they are working. Make sure you are not using 'i' in another loop. Remember 'i' is ` 0.0000 + 1.0000i`. Maybe you are using it in another part of the code.